# sql with group by providing unexpected result

Tags: sql, sybase

I am having a table like below

Table: variance

[image]

My result should come as

[image]

I know that the report is calculating based on sequence group when I tried to group by sequence I am not getting right out put. Is there any way to do that ?

This is what I tried. But not working

```
select count(sequence),values,Number 
from variance 
group by sequence.
```

I am using sybase

Thanks
Arun

Found a way to do that in a while statement. When ever I see increment in sequence increment the new sequence. Is there a way to do in a single query

Comment: Where is the `GROUP BY`, what rdbms are you using?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: And please don't use image links. Type the sample data in plain text instead. That's easier to work with and your request will still be readable in the future (when the images may have gone).

Comment: It seems to me you don't want to aggregate data at all, but show all records, only with row numbers instead of the stored sequence number.

Comment: Thanks I wont use image going forward. Is there a way I can do that without using a temp table or cursor ?

Comment: I need to create a new sequence based on stored sequence whenever I encounter an increment or change  in stored sequence, I need to increment the new sequnece

Answer (score 0):

You probably want use **[row_number](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/iqrefbb262.htm)**

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by sequence) as corrected_seq,
       Values,
       Number
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks, rownumber() will work only in sybaseIQ not in ASE. I am using Sybase ASE